# If row spaces of two $m\times n$ matrices are equal, then matrices are row-equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove that if two $m\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ over a field $F$ have the same row space, then they are row-equivalent.

Intuitively, it makes sense. Indeed, if $\mathrm{row}(A) = \mathrm{row}(B)$, then each row $[a_{i1}, ..., a_{in}]$ of $A$ is generated by rows of $B$ and vice versa, that if, for any $i = 1,...,m$ we have
$$[a_{i1},...,a_{in}] = c_{i1}[b_{i_11},...,b_{i_1n}] + ... + c_{it_i}[b_{i_{t_i}1},...,b_{i_{t_i}n}]$$
and
$$[b_{i1},...,b_{in}] = d_{i1}[a_{i'_11},...,a_{i'_1n}] + ...  d_{ip_i}[b_{i'_{p_i}1},...,b_{i'_{p_i}n}].$$

This seems similar to the condition an elementary operation being applied to a row, but I can't seem to make this final step to make it rigorous. One idea was to prove by induction is that is $A_k$ is equivalent to $A$, then $A_{k+1}$ is equivalent to $B$, where $(A_k)_{ij}$ is equal to $b_{ij}$ if $i < k$ and to $a_{ij}$ otherwise, but I have a feeling that this is wrong.

Edit: This question has been marked as a duplicate of another question for some reason. However, that question asked how to prove that two row-equivalent matrices have the same row space, while my question asks how to prove the converse.

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent if and only if there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $B=SA$.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for your comment, but I actually need the result in question to prove the equivalence of four conditions one of which is the existence of an invertible matrix. Of course, it may be not hard to prove it separately, in which case I may consider your approach. However, the question remains is how does it help us, that is, how can be deduce the existence of an invertible matrix $S$ such that $B = SA$ from $\mathrm{row}(A) = \mathrm{row}(B)$? I would really appreciate if you could give more details.

Comment: It mostly depends on what you know (or can use) about row equivalence. Perhaps posting the entire statement and your ideas about the other implications can shed more light.

Comment: @egreg I don't know much about it, only the facts that it doesn't change solutions to the systems of linear equations, that elementary matrices are invertible and that if $B$ is obtained from $A$ by applying a single elementary row operation, then $B = PA$ for an elementary matrix obtained from the identity matrix using the same elementary row operation.

Comment: @egreg Sorry to bother you, but I'm somewhat desperate. I can't find the source which treats my situation - most of the books I looked at don't care about proving this equivalence whether directly or as a corollary. I would greatly appreciate it if you could point me to a source which treats this question in any way, e.g. the way you suggested in the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, elementary row operations can be realized as multiplication by *elementary matrices*, that is, matrices differing from the identity by an elementary row operation. Such matrices are invertible.

Also, elementary row operations don't change the row space.

If you perform Gaussian elimination on $A$, the matrix in row echelon form you get has $k$ nonzero rows and the other are zero (at the bottom), where $k$ is the dimension of the row space. This echelon form $U$ is row equivalent to $A$ and $U=SA$, for some invertible matrix $S$.

Similarly, you can get a row echelon form $V=TB$ from $B$. So it's not restrictive to assume that $A$ and $B$ are in row echelon form: indeed, if $V=LU$ for an invertible matrix $L$, then $TB=LSA$ and $B=T^{-1}LSA$.

Note also that the nonzero rows of a matrix in row echelon form are linearly independent.

Since $A$ and $B$ have the same row space, they have the same number of nonzero rows. If $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$ and $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_k$ are the nonzero rows in $A$ and $B$, then
$$
a_i=\sum_{j=1}^kc_{ij}b_j
$$
and the $k\times k$ matrix $C=[c_{ij}]$ is invertible (why?). Now consider the invertible block matrix
$$
L=\begin{bmatrix} C & 0 \\ 0 & I_{m-k} \end{bmatrix}
$$
(the bottom right corner is the identity matrix; if $k=m$, just consider $L=C$).

Compute $LB$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I understand about half of it right now and in the process of doing so. However, I have zero ideas of $C$ would be invertible.

Comment: It seems I understand now why $C$ is invertible (because the row spaces coincide and rows are linearly independent), hence the inverse would be $D = (d_{ij})$ where $b_i = \sum_{j = 1}^k d_{ij}a_j$. Now all that remains is to check that the invertibility of $C$ implies the invertibility of $L$ and that an invertible matrix is a product of elementary matrices.

Comment: Dear egreg, could you, please, visit the following question? It is related to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3263795/229776