# How to prove that an invertible matrix is a product of elementary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix. I wonder how to prove that $A$ is a product of elementary matrices. I suspect that we need to transform it into the identity matrix by using elementary row operations, but how to do it exactly?

**P.S.** I've checked questions which could be considered similar and neither of them deals with this exact (general) situation. Please don't mark this question as a duplicate unless you find a precise answer.

Comment: You want to prove it is a product of *elementary matrices*. The RREF of an invertible matrix is the identity, because all columns become pivot columns.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for noticing a mistake, I will edit. However, but why all column become pivot column? How to prove it exactly?

Comment: @egreg Oh, I've found a source regarding this. Apparently, the only invertible RREG if the identity.

Comment: An invertible $n\times n$ matrix has rank $n$, so the elimination must find $n$ pivots.

Comment: @egreg Oh, that's clever. Thanks.

Comment: Try reducing it to reduced row echelon form using elementary matrices. If the matrix is invertible then its reduced row echelon form will be unit matrix $I$. Its standard textbook exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to translate each row elementary operation of the Gauss' pivot algorithm (for inverting a matrix) into a matrix product.

If you permute two rows, then you do a left multiplication with a permutation matrix.

If you multiply a row by a nonzero scalar then you do a left multiplication with a dilatation matrix.

If you add a multiple of a row to another row, then you do a left multiplication with a transvection matrix.

And the inverse is therefore the product of all those elementary matrices.

Answer (score 0):

If **A** is an invertible nxn matrix, $A\bar x  = \bar 0$ has only the trivial solution of $\bar 0$ because $$A^{-1}A\bar x = \bar x = A^{-1}\bar0 =\bar0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
This implies **A** is a product of elementary matrices because it implies **A** is row equivalent to **I**

Let's assume the **A** is in *REF*, if one of the diagonal elements were $0$ we would have a row filled with $0$'s and would have more unknowns than equations *(proof n>m implies nontrivial solution omitted)* and as a consequence has a nontrivial solution. Therefore, since we have no nontrivial solution $\ref{1}$, **I** is the *RREF* of **A** and **A** is composed of elementary row operations of **I**